# Dependency injection for Stripe.Net classes

Tags: c#, .net-core, stripe-payments

I created a service that allowed me to utilize the Stripe.Net classes (I called it a handler) but it wasn't really testable because in the methods I would instantiate the class. For example:

```
public Customer CreateCustomer(string email)
{
    var service = new CustomerService();

    return service.Create(new CustomerCreateOptions
    {
        Email = email
    });
}
```

which it's great when trying to create a test. So I figured I could just use the classes in Stripe.net instead of creating a handler. So I have tried doing this:

```
private static void AddTransients(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<Service<IStripeEntity>>();
    services.AddTransient<ICreatable<IStripeEntity, BaseOptions>>();, BaseOptions));
}
```

Which I through would allow me to pass the classes around my controllers like any other injected class. But when I launch my application I get this error:

> Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Stripe.IStripeEntity' for service type 'Stripe.IStripeEntity'.

So I tried registering the classes as generic like this:

```
private static void AddTransients(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient(typeof(Service<>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ICreatable<,>));
}
```

But when I run that, I get the same error. Does anyone know what I can do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by creating wrapper classes. Not the most ideal, but it works:

```
public class StripeCustomerService : IStripeCustomerService
{
    private readonly CustomerService _customerService;
    public StripeCustomerService() => _customerService = new CustomerService();

    public Customer Create(string email)
    {
        return _customerService.Create(new CustomerCreateOptions
        {
            Email = email
        });
    }

    public async Task<Customer> GetAsync(string id, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        await _customerService.GetAsync(id, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: This works but does this not make it untestable?

Comment: You could just change the signature to inject the CustomerService and then it would be testable

Answer (score 0):

CustomerService has a secondary constructor that receives IStripeClient. This is the class grain implementation **(I'm using orleans net)**.

```
public interface IStripeCustomerServiceGrain
{
    Customer CustomerCreate(CustomerCreateOptions createOptions);
}

public class StripeCustomerServiceGrain : Grain, IStripeCustomerServiceGrain
{
    private readonly CustomerService _customerService;

    public StripeCustomerServiceGrain(IStripeClient stripeClient)
    {
        _customerService = new CustomerService(stripeClient);
    }

    public Customer CustomerCreate(CustomerCreateOptions createOptions)
    {
        Customer customer = _customerService.Create(createOptions);

        return customer;
    }
}
```

This is my IOC configuration

```
        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = AppSettings.Stripe.SecretKey;
        StripeConfiguration.MaxNetworkRetries = 3;

        services.AddHttpClient("Stripe");
        services.AddTransient<IStripeClient, StripeClient>(s =>
        {
            var clientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            var httpClient = new SystemNetHttpClient(
                httpClient: clientFactory.CreateClient("Stripe"),
                maxNetworkRetries: StripeConfiguration.MaxNetworkRetries,
                enableTelemetry: StripeConfiguration.EnableTelemetry);

            return new StripeClient(apiKey: StripeConfiguration.ApiKey, httpClient: httpClient);
        });
```

Hope this help, and happy coding. :)